# Debian 7 can not boot, grub rescue show error: out of partition

Tags: debian, virtualbox, boot, grub, grub2

Debian 7 amd64 running in VirtualBox 5.0.10, on Windows 8.1 ent x64 host. This VM running more than 1 years. Use basic partition, NOT LVM or any Raid.

Today it's suddenly auto umount all disk, and mount / in readonly mode, I force reboot it on VirtualBox Manager. Then it cannot boot into the system anymore :doge

```sh
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error: out of partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)/
./ ../ lost+found/ var/ etc/ media/ vmlinuz sbin/ usr/ lib/ lib64/ selinux/ bin/ boot/
proc/ mnt/ tmp/ dev/ home/ root/ sys/ run/ srv/ opt/ initrd.img keybase/ lib32/ core
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos1)/boot/

error: out of partition.
grub rescue> ls (hd0)/
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue> ls (hd0,msdos5)/
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,msdos1)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
error: out of partition.
grub rescue> normal
Unknow command 'normal'
grub rescue>
```

I used debian-7.11.0-amd64-netinst.iso into Debian's rescue mode, but on the final step, it cannot mount /target at any partition, display this warning:

```sh
An error occurred while mounting the device you entered for your root file system (/dev/sda1) on /target
Please check the syslog for more information.
```

The /var/log/syslog

```
rescue-mode: partitions found: /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sda5
rescue-mode: selected root device '/dev/sda1'
rescue: umount: can't umount /target: Invalid argument
kernel: EXT2-fs (sda1): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (244)
kernel: EXT3-fs (sda1): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_check_descriptors: Block bitmap for group 128 not in group (block 811458560)!
kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): group descriptors corrupted!
kernel: FAT-fs (sda1): utf8 is not a recommented IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
rescue: mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /target failed: Invalid argument
rescue-mode: mount '/dev/sda1' /target failed
kernel: atkbd serio0: Spurious NAK on isa0060/serio0. Some program migh be trying access hardware directly.
rescue-mode: partitions found: /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sda5
rescue-mode: selected root device '/dev/sda2'
rescue: umount: can't umount /target: Invalid argument
kernel: isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sda2, iso_blknum=16, block=32
kernel: EXT2-fs (sda2): error: unable to read superblock
kernel: EXT3-fs (sda2): error: unable to read superblock
kernel: EXT4-fs (sda2): unable to read superblock
kernel: REISERFS warning (device sda2): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev sda2, block 8, size 1024)
kernel: REISERFS warning (device sda2): sh-2006 read_super_block: bread failed (dev sda2, block 64, size 1024)
kernel: FAT-fs (sda2): utf8 is not a recommented IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
rescue: mount: mounting /dev/sda2 on /target failed: Invalid argument
rescue-mode: mount '/dev/sda2' /target failed
rescue-mode: partitions found: /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sda5
rescue-mode: selected root device '/dev/sda5'
rescue: umount: can't umount /target: Invalid argument
kernel: FAT-fs (sda5): utf8 is not a recommented IO charset for FAT filesystems, filesystem will be case sensitive!
rescue: mount: mounting /dev/sda5 on /target failed: Invalid argument
rescue-mode: mount '/dev/sda5' /target failed
```

**update: 2016-11-14**

You're right `DerfK`, it's virtual hardware corrupt.

In Debian's rescue mode not mount any partition, running `fsck.ext4 -ycf /dev/sda1` fixed it.

Comment: Have you checked on the host for disk errors? Sounds like the disk image is corrupt.

Comment: I think host system has not problem, I reboot the host more than 2 times. Could you please tell me how to check the host for disk? I used Plextor PX-128M6Pro SSD.

Comment: @DerfK I use CrystalDiskInfo 7.0.4 x64 checked my SSD, the `Health Status` is `Good 100%`.  `Total Host Reads`: 6688 GB, `Total Host Writes`: 8386 GB, `Total NAND Writeds`: 16772 GB, `Power On Count`: 1233 count, `Power On Hours`: 2453 hours. SSD Firmware version is `1.02`